# How to add tab navigation below the header?

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I want make a tab navigation below the header.
and when one of tab is clicked, show sidebar of the tab and its contents.
like this

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iQ9vCslTwUt6Zo4-WLHr_vjAL8gvi_3A

for that, where should I start and how?
after many tries, I think I may be on the wrong way or wrong direction.

- made a TabNavComponent inside @theme/components
- put it in theme.module.ts
- and bring it somewhere in the template of page.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-pages',
  styleUrls: ['pages.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <ngx-one-column-layout>
      <tab-nav></tab-nav>
      <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ngx-one-column-layout>
  `,
})
```

- it shows nothing about my new tab nav.
- not even in the webpage source.

- it was the same, nothing was showed or wrong
- in @theme/layouts/one-column/one-column.layout.ts
- in @theme/components/header/header.component.html
- ....

Answer (score 0):

If you could consider doing it manually first, it’s realy easy doing a tab nav. It’s just a styled horizontal

```
 <ul><li>
```

with routerLinks in it. Basically it’s just a styled leftmenu nav. 
I could send you some ex code

Comment: if I could, I want to use existing component. since I couldn't figure it out, I tried to make it manually.